# I wrote a letter for an hour

Tags: past-simple, adverbials

I've just read that it is not possible to say "I wrote a letter for three hours", but I've seen many examples like "I read the book for an hour" or "I watched the film for an hour".

What is the difference?

Is it because "I wrote a letter" is interpreted as having been completed and "I read a book for an hour" is not interpreted as completed, because reading a book usually takes longer than an hour?

Comment: I don't think "I wrote a letter for three hours" is *wrong*, but the more idiomatic way to say it is "I spent three hours writing a letter".

Comment: Wrote just isn't used that way -- wrote indicates a completed action, not an ongoing action. That's why you can say "I wrote a letter" (it's done), or "I wrote a poem." (it's done). You can't say "I wrote a poem for three hours." Other verbs don't work the same way.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I don't understand your answer. Why does "wrote" indicate completed action and "read" doesn't? To read a book and to write a letter are both telic activities.

Comment: What part is unclear? As I said, wrote is not used that way. It sounds like you are making ELL mistake #40404 -- thinking of abstract categories and then trying to fit verbs into them. People don't think, "Oh, that's a telic verb! I must use this and that." I doubt any other language is perfectly logically constructed either.

Comment: @FeliniusRex What is unclear is that "I wrote a letter for three hours" is not correct and " I read a book for two hours" is. You haven't answered that.

Comment: @stangdon Does "I spent three hours writing a letter" imply the letter has been completed?

Comment: @anouk  I would say it implies it, but does not necessarily state it for a fact.  If it were something like "I spent three hours writing a letter, then went and had dinner at Petrov's, where (etc. etc.)" I would assume the letter was finished.  If it were "I spent three hours writing a letter, before throwing my pen down in disgust at my inability to express myself", that means the letter was not finished.

Comment: Feel free to read English novels, short stories, and so on. You won't find it used the way you want to use it. There's a reason for that. The word just isn't used that way, and there is not a rule to tell you why.

Comment: Detective: **What did you do last night after 7:00 pm**? Person being questioned: **I wrote a letter for an hour, then I cooked for two hours, ate what I cooked and fed the dog and was in bed by 11:00 pm**. ///Ain't that good enough fer yous?

Comment: It would be so unusual for a letter to be so long that it took three hours to write, that the sentence sounds really strange in that form.

Comment: Context is everything.  Resistance to it is futile.

Comment: Wow, three hours? That must've been some letter! That said, I don't know where you're getting your information, but there's nothing wrong with saying, "I wrote a letter for three hours." That's perfectly natural and grammatical. Some have commented otherwise, but that's a consequence of imagining an ESL speaker say it. If another native English speaker were to say that to them, they'd take no exception, not find its wording odd, do any doubletake, or even blink. Someone asks, "What'd you do last night?" I answer, "I wrote a letter for three hours." That's A-OK, a totally natural thing to say.